# Add a column from one pandas dataframe to another when both are indexed differently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python. I have two pandas dataframes that are indexed differently. I want to copy a column from one to another. 
Dataframe 1: Holds the id and class that each image belongs to

```
      ID  index  class
0  10472  10472      0
1   7655   7655      0
2   6197   6197      0
3   9741   9741      0
4   9169   9169      0
```

Dataframe 2: Holds the id of the image in index and the image data in data columns

```
                                                    data
index                                                   
5882   [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 255, 0], [255...
360    [[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0...
1906   [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 255, 0], [255...
3598   [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [232, 232, 247, 25], [34...
231    [[[255, 255, 255, 0], [234, 234, 234, 0], [57,...
```

I want to iterate through the dataframe1 and pick up the image id and look up the dataframe 2 for the matching id in the index and copy the 'data' column over to dataframe1. How could i do this (in a performance optimal way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for match data need same types, so if get different:

```
print (df1['index'].dtype)    
int64
print (df2.index.dtype)   
object
```

there are 2 possible solutions - convert index to integers by:

```
df2.index = df2.index.astype(int)
```

Or column to strings:

```
df1['index'] = df1['index'].astype(str)
```

---

Then use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by column `data` in `df2`:

```
df1['data'] = df1['index'].map(df2['data'])
```

Or if need add multiple columns from `df2` (e.g. in real data) use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df1.join(df2, on=['index'])
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion, but it returns 'NaN' for all values:

Comment: What is `print (df1.dtypes)` and `print (df2.index)` ? Need same types, `integers` or `strings`

Comment: This is what is returned (in that order):
ID        int64
index     int64
class     int64
data     object
dtype: object
Index([u'0', u'1', u'10', u'100', u'1000', u'10000', u'10001', u'10002',
       u'10003', u'10004',
       ...
       u'9990', u'9991', u'9992', u'9993', u'9994', u'9995', u'9996', u'9997',
       u'9998', u'9999'],
      dtype='object', name=u'index', length=12533)

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, but it looks like the df2 index is of type u'index'

Comment: I see it, try `df2.index = df2.index.astype(int)` before my solution

Comment: @Praveen - Added to answer also :) Thank you.